# Why preg_match_all returning 2 results?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

Why preg_all_match returning two results? Where is the problem? Thanks for your helps.

```
    <?php
$site=file_get_contents("http://www.site.gen.tr");
preg_match_all('@<div class=\'search\'>(.*?)<\/div>@si',$site,$baslik); ?>

<select name="sub_category"  id="sub_category_id">
<option value="" selected="selected">Bir Sey Seçin</option>
   <?php for($i=0; $i < count($baslik); $i++) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $baslik[0][$i];?>"><?php echo $baslik[0][$i]; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>   
</select>
```

Comment: That's not two results, it's the full match and the content of the first group that you have (`(.*?)`).

Comment: What are these two results?

Comment: Returning just two options in combobox with this code. But there are much more.

Comment: Hint: Iterate over `$baslik[0]` for all the matches.

Comment: Another hint: Using `var_dump` would *really* help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($baslik[0]); $i++) {
```